# SSMS Import / Export Data Wizard to Azure Synapse Issue

Tags: ssms, azure-synapse

Gooday everyone!

**SSMS Ver 18.9.2**

I'm having an issue trying to export data using the Data Import/Export wizard in SSMS to our Data warehouse. I keep receiving this error:

*cursor support is not an implemented feature for sql server parallel datawarehousing tds endpoint. (microsoft sql server native client 11.0)*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a work around, or maybe it was just the way I should have done it all the while.

For selecting a destination:
Destination: .Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer
Data Source: Server Name
Initial Catalog: Database
User ID & Password

I hope this helps someone else down the road!

Comment: Have you looked at Synapse Pathway, currently in preview?  It's supposed to be more geared towards migrations to Synapse, dedicated SQL pools really.

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing or exporting and what connection have you selected.